# Unable to resolve module `rn-fetch-blob`?

Tags: react-native

**when I run the native code showing this error and my react-native is the latest version can you have any idea this rn-fetch-blob is supporting latest version react native or any solution to solve this problem ?**

```
bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `rn-fetch-blob` from `src\containers\GroupFeed\FullImage.js`: rn-fetch-blob could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\New RN Projects\InnoEvent\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\New RN Projects\InnoEvent\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\New RN Projects\InnoEvent\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (D:\New RN Projects\InnoEvent\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at D:\New RN Projects\InnoEvent\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (D:\New RN Projects\InnoEvent\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at D:\New RN
```

**here is my package.json:-**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
     "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.6.4",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.4",


  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",

    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",

  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you installed it properly?

Comment: @GauravRoy yes.i have installed all latest version

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it?